# Connecting to Oracle Database Using Service Name Instead of SID

Tags: oracle, service-name

The idea here is to be able to connect to my Database using the service name instead of SID. Here's my `tnsnames.ora`:

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: C:\Users\jj\Downloads\WINDOWS.X64_193000_db_home\NETWORK\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

LISTENER_ORCL =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))


ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl.myDomain.int)
    )
  )
  
DB_PBD =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = myServiceName)
    )
  )
```

And here's my `listener.ora`:

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: C:\Users\jj\Downloads\WINDOWS.X64_193000_db_home\NETWORK\ADMIN\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\Users\jj\Downloads\WINDOWS.X64_193000_db_home)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\Users\jj\Downloads\WINDOWS.X64_193000_db_home\bin\oraclr19.dll")
    )
   (SID_DESC = 
        (GLOBAL_DBNAME = orcl)
        (ORACLE_HOME = C:\Users\jj\Downloads\WINDOWS.X64_193000_db_home)
        (SID_NAME = orcl)
    )
   (SID_DESC = 
        (GLOBAL_DBNAME = DB_PBD)
        (ORACLE_HOME = C:\Users\jj\Downloads\WINDOWS.X64_193000_db_home)
        (SID_NAME = orcl)
    )   
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )
```

So far, I'm able to establish the connection using `ORCL`, `orcl.myDomain.int` and `DB_PBD`.

However, when I try to connect to it using `myServiceName` which is the `SERVICE_NAME` of the entry `DB_PBD`, I get the following error:

```
TNS-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
```

Is there something wrong with the way myServiceName is defined?

**EDIT**:
When I viewed my service list in my database, I didn't find myServiceName:

```
SQL> select name from V$SERVICES;

    NAME
    ----------------------------------------------------------------
    orclXDB
    SYS$BACKGROUND
    orcl.myDomain.int
    SYS$USERS
    orclpdb
```

Should I add it here as well?

Comment: How exactly did you define/create service?

Comment: I just added another entry in my tnsnames.ora and named the field SERVICE_NAME `myServiceName`.

Comment: All entries in your tnsnames are service names and no SID's.You need to use dbms_service package to create and start service or netmgr on Windows(not sure about unix/linux)

Comment: Refer this [link](https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/dbms_service)

Comment: Noticed Oracle home directory your Database version is 19c and on Windows.You can invoke `netmgr` from run/start menu/command prompt or follow the above link.

Comment: Thank you, your link helped me a lot.

Comment: When dealing with TNS-12514, the _very first_ thing I'd want to see is the output of 'lsnrctl status' and 'lsnrctl services'.  That is much more informative than the content of listener.ora.